# Building relations between switch buttons

Tags: javascript, html, relationship

Guys i am trying to make relations between switch buttons.Each button represents a device. For example, if i turn off  x device it will turn off y and z. But in case y is off it will turn couple more. I tried with switch case statement but my code is getting messy. I tried to find if is a javascript library but with no results. Any idea?

```
function hm1() {
    var hlektro1 = document.getElementById("device_engine1").checked;

    switch (hlektro1) {
        case (hlektro1 = true):
            document.getElementById("device_x").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("device_1").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("device_NAUTICAL").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("device_2").checked = false;
            break
        case (hlektro1 = false):
            document.getElementById("device_x").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("device_1").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("device_NAUTICAL").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("device_2").checked = true;
            break
    }
}

function gps() {
    var gpsdevice = document.getElementById("device_x").checked;

    switch (gpsdevice) {
        case (gpsdevice = true):
            document.getElementById("device_55").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("device_123").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("device_NAUTICAL").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("device_CAMERA").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("device_14").checked = false;
            break
        case (gpsdevice = false):
            document.getElementById("device_55").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("device_123").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("device_NAUTICAL").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("device_CAMERA").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("device_14").checked = true;
            break
    }
}
```

sample of switch button:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="engine1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="device_Ηλεκτρομηχανη1" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="device_engine1" onclick="hm1()">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: MDN: "The [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) evaluates an expression, **matching the expression's value to a case clause**, and executes statements associated with that case."

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this statement `case (hlektro1 = true):` ? Assigning value `true` to `hlektro1` ?

Comment: @Andreas i think you just oil my gears. do you think switch case with if statement combination is the right way?

Comment: @Rohit What you mean? is a standard switch case statement

Comment: @kostasM. No, that's why I've posted the link ;)  `switch (hlektro1.checked) { case true: ... break; case false: ... break; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `id` to all the dependend checkboxes as `class`.
And on `change` of the "controlling" checkbox get all the dependend checkboxes and set the `checked` state accordingly.

Something like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#control").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var checkbox = e.target,
    dependendCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("." + checkbox.id);

  for (var i = 0; i < dependendCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    dependendCheckboxes[i].checked = checkbox.checked;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="control">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="device_engine1" />device_engine1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="device_x" />device_x</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="device_engine1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="device_x" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="device_engine1 device_x" />
</div>
```

Comment: press device_engine1 device_x and depress device_x again. The values it will be different if you press only device_engine1 only.

Comment: That's just a minimal showcase for the suggested method

Comment: i found the solution, keeping my messy code ;) one switch case statement inside another switch case statement